# Leaving a project in Firebase but doesn't have the ownership for the project

Tags: firebase

I need to leave a project in **Firebase** and I have no option for to leave the project because I don't have the ownership of the project. I am a member in that project and need to leave that project, as its development has been stopped several months before

Is there any option to do that? I also need to delete it from **Google Developer Console**.

Answer (score 27):

This is not possible right now.

You cannot remove yourself from the Firebase project, because you also cannot remove yourself from the Google Cloud project.

[Google was made aware that people need this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35889152) in 2011 (sic!) but until now did not add this feature. There is a [Change.org petition](http://chng.it/9vj9dtj8FX) now which will hopefully get enough developers to sign.

So if you really need this: sign the petition, click the star in Google's [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35889152) and pray.

Comment: +1 I signed the petition. I hope Google will take action even if it doesn't reach the number of required signatures. This is absurd.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that normal member couldn't leave project. Only way is to ask one of the owners to remove you from the project.

Comment: Yes, there is no way to do that it seems. I have contacted the owner of the project and asked him to remove me.

Comment: Not all owners unfortunately can do it according to their competence in this area)))

Answer (score 1):

Ask one the project owners to remove you instead.

Answer (score 0):

It will show us like this....

[image]

Which makes you believe you are going out of project but next moment it will show you like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By mistake, I removed owner user (myself) from the only project I have on my Firebase account. Now, I have no access to this project as well as I can't create a new project on the same account for a strange error (as you can see in the screenshot) as I have no project in my account.

I still have access to my project on Google Cloud but it doesn't help to retrieve me as owner to my project.

[image]