# Firebase Console contains a project I did NOT create

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I'm cleaning up my Google Firebase console, deleting some projects I created while learning about Firebase console and stuff.

There is a project here that I did NOT create. And, I'm not the owner, either, because I can't delete it.

In the Authentication tab, nothing. No databases defined.

Under project settings, the support email dropdown has a random email address selected, with my address listed second. In the Users & Permissions tab, there are about 8 users listed, none of which are me. Again, I'm not the owner, so I can't disable the users.

Some internet sleuthing brings me to some person associated with some company in Nairobi, Kenya. (Maybe he's a prince!)

Now, I like to think I'm pretty secure, IT-wise. I use Apple's keychain. I have different, randomly generated passwords for every single account I use. The password for this Google account is randomly generated. I have also had 2-factor authentication on longer than I've had a Firebase console. I'm trying to think of other public-facing vectors that this person might have used, but I can't think of others. Maybe you have thoughts on this?

I've sent a support request to Google, but the options under Urgency don't include "Someone has injected a project into my Firebase console."

How can I find out who set this up?

Comment: Why would you vote to close? Please, do tell.

Comment: As much as people would like to help, the correct avenue for this is Firebase technical support. There is much about your account that readers here do not know about, and that information will be available to Firebase staff.

Comment: I always find it curious when a question is closed AFTER someone has given an answer. StackOverflow used to be about people helping people in their area of expertise, now it's about nitpicking and policing questions, finding reasons *not* to help people....Tell me how my questions is materially different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397838/leaving-a-project-in-firebase-but-doesnt-have-the-ownership-for-the-project. (Hint: it's not.)

Comment: People who vote to close a question should be required to put at least as much time/effort into explaining why as the person spent asking it.

Comment: You may just be unfamiliar with the kind of peer moderation we do here - it's how closure has worked for years. If you are happy with the answer Frank gave, then that's great - getting answers and getting a close vote are separate actions. Frank works for Firebase so is unlikely to vote to close in this case - since you are a customer! That is understandable. By my good faith assessment, the question is still not on topic, for the reason given.

Comment: You are right that there is some inconsistency between closures. That is unavoidable in a site of this scale. We have long said that the existence of an old off-topic question that is still open is not evidence that questions of the same are on-topic. I think that ethic has been mentioned many a time on _Meta Stack Overflow_.

Comment: This question appears to require system-level access to Firebase that readers do not have access to. If you want to modify it so it can be answered by any Firebase user, then that is fine. My guess is that if you want to trace someone who did something in Firebase, only Technical Support can do that. Indeed, Frank has advised the same.

Comment: Well, you can add that phrase back in if you like, I don't think it makes a difference to the nature of the question - it is still unavoidably requires technical support. I edited because I found the question vague and chatty, and questions are better (at least here) when they have some focus.

Comment: " Frank works for Firebase so is unlikely to vote to close in this case - since you are a customer!" You might want to check my history before making that assumption. ;-)

In this case I just know the problem comes up occasionally, and decided it might be more helpful going forward to have an answer with both the reasoning, and the pointer to Firebase support.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: apologies, tone is rather hard to impart here. My comment was intended to have a kindly tone, and I thought your answer was helpful. It was not intended as a criticism. I am glad to hear you are assisting with closing - we need as many people helping with that as possible `:-)`.

Comment: No worries whatsoever (hence the smiley). 

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when a large group is added as a collaborator to a project, and you're a member of that group. I have dozens of these that were assigned to something like all@google.com.

Since somebody chose to add that group, it's not a security risk for me, although it is annoying. The best I can say is that these projects tend to drift to the bottom of the list over time, but it's not ideal.

It is unlikely that anyone here can do anything about the specific project though, so [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting (like looking at the project to see *why* it shows up for you).

**Update**: I just noticed this similar [post to the firebase-talk mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?oldui=1#!topic/firebase-talk/spqJeMtGkEk) around the same time, so I'd recommend keeping an eye on that too.

Comment: Thanks, Frank. So...it's *not* my project? I'm just a member? But, I'm not even in the list of users......All the other email addresses are variations on the owners email address. I don't understand why he'd add himself multiple times and also l'il ol' me

Is there a way to leave the project?

Comment: It is indeed not your project, and you can't get charged for it unless you're the billing owner. The linked thread explains: if you were see if because being part of a group, the only way to get rid of the project is to leave the group. If you can't find a group, support may be able to figure out how you are in it.