# Unrecognized Firebase Project. I'm hoping it is a demo project

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

Is this perhaps some firebase demo project or is my account being hacked? Could it be that someone have given me access to their project? If so, shouldn’t I have gotten an email at least? I have never given anybody access to my account.

Went to my Firebase today and there is a project name Alfatawa with 14 users.  What is worse, I can not delete it. I goggle searched that name and nothing came up. I asked Firebase support for help just now but I was wondering if any of you have experienced anything like it.
[image]

Comment: There is no such demo projects in firebase with users and stuff like this as far as I know. Also I don't think you have been hacked as well by the looks of it you are just a part of someone else's project. Maybe someone accidentally invited you into their projects or something, best thing to reach out to support and leave the project if possible.

Comment: I've tried deleting it but can't. I don't see any option to remove myself from it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397838/leaving-a-project-in-firebase-but-doesnt-have-the-ownership-for-the-project

Comment: This means that somebody added you to the project, typically by adding a group that you're a member of. The only ways to remove the project are 1) to be removed from the group, 2) to remove the group from the project.

Comment: It would be better if you blurred out the email addresses shown in this image.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that somebody added you to the project, typically by adding a group that you're a member of.

The only ways to remove the project are:

- to be removed from the group.
- to get a project owner to remove the group from the project.

This project is no security risk for you, as nobody in the new project can see any of your existing projects.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the response I received from Firebase Support:**

"You are seeing the project Alfatawa because the Google Group 'firebase-talk@googlegroups.com' was previously listed as a project member. Project Owners are allowed to add Google Groups to their projects, and anyone who is in the group will be able to access the project. You should no longer be able to access it because the project owner was able to remove the group as project member.

In case this happens in the future, the fastest way to be certain the project is removed from your console is to leave that group.

Do know that while this project shows up on your console, you are not responsible for it, and it will not charge you. There is no impact from having this project on your console. You could simply ignore it, and not looking at any data it may contain."